# Heroku "Globalize3" migration fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, heroku

I'm deployinh a ruby on rails app on heroku. On localhost everything went well, but when running

heroku rake db:migrate

to run the migration on heroku my migration fails with this error:

> rake aborted! An error has occurred,
>   this and all later migrations
>   canceled:
>
> PGError: ERROR:  current transaction
>   is aborted, commands ignored until end
>   of transaction block : CREATE TABLE
>   "product_translations" ("id" serial
>   primary key, "product_id" integer,
>   "locale" character varying(255),
>   "description" text, "created_at"
>   timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp)
>
> (See full trace by running task with
>   --trace)

My migration is built as follows:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :image_path
      t.text :description
      t.timestamps
    end
    Product.create_translation_table! :description => :text
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :products
    Product.drop_translation_table!
  end
end
```

It seems the query used to create the table for globalize3 (the Product.create_translation_table! method) fails.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[They](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3/issues/27) are saying that it is because of a gem error.

```
gem 'globalize3', :path => 'vendor/plugins/globalize3'
```